# Copy data based on column header from workbook1 to workbook2. Does not copy data after blank cells

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am naive to macros and i tried the below code to copy data based on column header from workbook1 to workbook2. But it copies only the rows with data. I have some blank rows in between. Any help will be much appreciated.

I presume the End(x1Down).Copy is stopping to proceed further. Instead I tried using EntireColumn.Copy, but it spolis the formating in the destination workbook.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
Dim headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)),Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Find the last row using [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then construct your range. You should avoid using `xlDown` as explained in the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a block of non-empty cells `Range.End()` will bring you to the last used cell.

If you are at the end of a block of non-empty cells `Range.End()` will bring you to the next used cell or the end of the column.

```
Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
```

Comment: Excellent, this works. You saved my time and many thanks Thomas.

Comment: Also thanks to Siddharth to enlighten with great knowledge of using proper syntax. Appreciate all your contributions. Thanks once again to all of you

Answer (score 1):

in your question you mentioned different workbooks and if that is the case, you may want to specify the workbook names as well to ensure the program runs predictably.

e.g.

```
Set headers = Workbooks("wb1").Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")
```

Assuming that this is just about copying from one worksheet to another, then you might want to heed Siddharth Rout's advice on using `End(xlUp)` instead due to the presence of blank rows.

e.g.

```
Worksheets("ws1").Range(Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0), Worksheets("ws1").Range("Z1048576").End(xlUp))
```

Please note I dont exactly like this method since it isnt very dynamic but because of the way header is set...and the lack of information on your worksheet structure, i have given this example to illustrate the use of `End(xlUp)`.

Also please note that if you are using older versions of Excel, do change 1048576 to 65536 (or any row that you deem safe for your worksheet)